# Training Machine Learning in Production

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

Is there a way to train your machine learning model in the cloud? Or does it really have to be batch training? i.e. (Pull some data on SQL, then feed that to the model)

What i was thinking is implementing my own model from scratch, use Stochastic Gradient Descent to update the parameters for every row from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like [GCP AI platform](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/)

1. You can use [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/) to store your data and do some analytics and perform inbuilt ML models.
2. [AI Platform Notebooks](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-notebooks/) for manage your notebooks
3. [Check this list for built in algorithms in GCP](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/algorithms/)
4. Or if you have a your model, you can use cloud resources to run your model.[check this link how to use GCP resources for your model](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/training-overview)

Answer (score -1):

You can train machine learning models in the cloud, and it doesn't have to be batch training only. Cloud services support both batch and online training. Online training, such as using Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD), is ideal for real-time adaptation to changing data patterns. Ensure efficient data pipelines, scalability, monitoring, and cost management when implementing your model. For more details, consider reading the article "[Machine Learning in the Cloud: What Are the Benefits?"](https://symphony-solutions.com/insights/machine-learning-in-the-cloud-what-are-the-benefits)